# How can I get just the first xml node entry from a list of multiple xml node entries (with namespace) in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-namespaces

I have my xml file content(testdata.xml) as below.

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.mycomp.report/Get-Integration-Events">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Integration_Event>SomeInfo - 04/17/2017 11:29:14.061 (Completed)</wd:Integration_Event>
        <wd:Integration_ID>123456789a123</wd:Integration_ID>
        <wd:Integration_Event_Status>Completed</wd:Integration_Event_Status>
        <wd:Actual_Start_Date_and_Time>2017-04-17T11:29:00-07:00</wd:Actual_Start_Date_and_Time>
        <wd:Actual_Completed_Date_and_Time>2017-04-17T11:29:23.085-07:00</wd:Actual_Completed_Date_and_Time>
        <wd:Request_Name>
            SomeInfo - 04/17/2017 11:29:14.061 (Completed)
        </wd:Request_Name>
        <wd:Response_Message>Integration Completed.</wd:Response_Message>
        <wd:referenceID>SomeRefId</wd:referenceID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Integration_Event>SomeInfo - 04/17/2017 11:29:14.061 (Completed)</wd:Integration_Event>
        <wd:Integration_ID>234567890b234</wd:Integration_ID>
        <wd:Integration_Event_Status>Completed</wd:Integration_Event_Status>
        <wd:Actual_Start_Date_and_Time>2017-04-17T11:29:00-07:00</wd:Actual_Start_Date_and_Time>
        <wd:Actual_Completed_Date_and_Time>2017-04-17T11:29:23.085-07:00</wd:Actual_Completed_Date_and_Time>
        <wd:Request_Name>
            SomeInfo - 04/17/2017 11:29:14.061 (Completed)
        </wd:Request_Name>
        <wd:Response_Message>Integration Completed.</wd:Response_Message>
        <wd:referenceID>SomeRefId</wd:referenceID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        ............. around 50+ similar entries
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

I want to extract the value of first occurrence of the tag `<wd:Integration_Event_Status>`. If the value returned is "Completed", then I want to extract all the children elements of the first occurrence of the tag `<wd:Report_Entry>` and put the retrieved elements into an another xml file, say extracted_result.xml.

I tried the below powershell code to retrieve the value of the `<wd:Integration_Event_Status>` tag, it returned the correct value when I had just one occurrence of `<wd:Report_Entry>` but when I had multiple entries `<wd:Report_Entry>` it's giving me an error.
code:

```
$baseDir = "C:\myfolder"
$configFile = "$baseDir\testdata.xml"
[xml]$confXml = Get-Content $configFile
$eventStatus = $confXml.GetElementsByTagName("wd:Integration_Event_Status").'#text'
Write-Host $eventStatus
```

How to get this working using powershell ?

Comment: `$confXml.GetElementsByTagName("wd:Integration_Event_Status")[0].'#text'`

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen
Also how can I extract all the children elements of the first occurrence of the tag <wd:Report_Entry> ?